# Detect Chrome running in headless mode from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, headless-browser

With the release of Chrome 59, "headless" mode is [now available](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5678767817097216) in stable builds for Linux and macOS (and soon also Windows with Chrome 60). This allows us to run a full-featured version of Chrome without any visible UI, a great capability to have for automated testing. [Here are examples.](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)

```sh
chrome --headless --disable-gpu --dump-dom https://stackoverflow.com/
```

In my JavaScript test runner, I like to record as much information as possible about the browser being used, to help isolate issues. For example, I record many of the properties of `navigator`, including the current browser plugins:

```js
JSON.stringify(Array.from(navigator.plugins).map(p => p.name))
```

```js
["Chrome PDF Viewer","Widevine Content Decryption Module","Shockwave Flash","Native Client","Chrome PDF Viewer"]
```

My understanding is that Chrome *should* behave identically in headless mode, but I have enough experience to be skeptical of a new feature that may significantly change the rendering pipeline.

For now, I am going to run tests in both modes. I would like to the test runner to record whether headless mode is being used. I could pass this information in the test configurations, but I'd rather have a pure JavaScript solution that I can build into the test runner itself. However, I haven't been able to find any browser interface that reveals whether headless mode is active.

Is there any way to detect if Chrome is running in headless mode from JavaScript?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can check [`navigator.webdriver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/webdriver) property which is:

> The `webdriver` read-only property of the `navigator` interface indicates
>   whether the user agent is controlled by automation.
>
> ...
>
> The `navigator.webdriver` property is true when in:
>
> **Chrome** The `--enable-automation` or the `--headless` flag is used.
>   **Firefox** The `marionette.enabled` preference or `--marionette` flag is passed.

The W3C WebDriver Recommendation [describes it](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dom-navigatorautomationinformation-webdriver) as follows:

> **`navigator.webdriver`** Defines a standard way for co-operating user agents to inform the document that it is controlled by WebDriver, for example so that alternate code paths can be triggered during automation.

Answer (score 36):

The **user agent** string [includes `HeadlessChrome` instead of `Chrome`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/cce7c0a2dcdbcb203d207baa4a01f24df5a594e5/headless/public/headless_browser.cc#19). This is probably the signal that you're intended to look for, so you could use:

```
/\bHeadlessChrome\//.test(navigator.userAgent)
```

Other interesting signals include:

- It looks like `window.chrome` is undefined when headless.
- `[innerWidth, innerHeight]` is `[800, 600]` (hardcoded in `headless_browser.cc`), while `[outerWidth, outerHeight]` is `[0, 0]` (which shouldn't usually happen).

Comment: user agent string can be overridden by setting a chrome option.

Comment: `window.chrome` is `undefined` in Firefox and Safari, so I would avoid that one...

Answer (score 9):

Just read [this article by Antoine Vastel](http://antoinevastel.github.io/bot%20detection/2017/08/05/detect-chrome-headless.html) which provides a few ways:

- testing user agent with `/HeadlessChrome/.test(window.navigator.userAgent)`, but this is easily spoofed
- testing plugins with `navigator.plugins.length == 0`
- testing languages with `navigator.languages == ""`
- testing WebGL vendor and renderer info (see article for interesting details)
- testing supported features as detected by Modernizr: it seems "hairlines" are not supported (hidpi/retina hairlines, which are CSS borders with less than 1px in width, for being physically 1px on hidpi screens). Test is `!Modernizr["hairline"]`.
- testing size of placeholder for missing image. Insert an image with invalid URL, and test for `image.width == 0 && image.height == 0` in `image.onerror` (they found this one to be the most robust).

Can't speak for Google's motivations (*is Headless Chrome only about facilitating tests of web applications? Hmmm...*), but this could be seen as a list of bugs that might get fixed someday, so one has to wonder for how long those tests will work :)

Comment: I just noticed after posting this that Josh Lee has mentioned this in a comment under the question yesterday. I read the same article and remembered this question from last month... I hope I stroke the right balance between advertising for the original author and did not plagiarize. If this is too much I'd be OK to edit, remove, etc. (thanks Jeremy for the edition)

Comment: navigator.languages == "", does not seems to be a valid test. My preferred browser language is "en-GB" while my preferred system language is "en-US". navigator.languages in normal chromium browser returns ["en-GB", "en-US", "en"], while on headless chromium returns [ 'en-US' ]

Answer (score 5):

`navigator.plugins` should contain an array of plugins that are present within the browser (like Flash, ActiveX, or Java applets). For `headless` browser it'll be nullable.

As a part of security check it can be used `alert`, for headless it'll be ignored:

```
var start = Date.now();
alert('Press OK');
var elapse = Date.now() - start;
if (elapse < 15) {
    console.log("headless environment detected");
}
```

Several techniques for detecting headless browsers are discussed in the OWASP AppSecUSA 2014 talk *Headless Browser Hide & Seek* ([video](https://youtu.be/95sydbXK_7k), [slides](https://www.slideshare.net/SergeyShekyan/shekyan-zhang-owasp)) by Sergey Shekyan and Bei Zhang.

Comment: I confirm that I see `navigator.plugins.length === 0` in headless Chrome. Test command: `chrome --headless --disable-gpu --dump-dom 'data:text/html,<!doctype html><body><script>document.body.innerHTML = \`plugins: ${navigator.plugins.length} ${Array.from(navigator.plugins).map(p => p.name)}\`;</script>'`

Comment: But I got "false-positive" for you. I'm using Chrome on my Android phone and it returns `navigator.plugins.length === 0`. So, better don't use this.

Comment: Yeah testing on chromium on linux also returns plugings: 0. So this is not a reliable test.

Answer (score 5):

The best solution I have so far is this hack. I wouldn't use it in prod code, but might in testing.

Chrome's pop-up blocker is usually enabled for all web sites, but it's disabled in headless mode. We can use the ability to open pop-ups as a fairly accurate proxy for being in headless mode. The implementation is simple: try to `open(...)` a window, and check whether we get `null` (indicating that it was blocked) instead of a `Window` object. If we do open one, close it as quickly as possible.

```
function canPopUp() {
  var w = open("");
  if (w !== null) {
    w.close();
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

var isHeadless = canPopUp;
```

For a quick example, you can try the following with and without the `--headless` flag:

> `` chrome --headless --disable-gpu --dump-dom 'data:text/html,<!doctype html><body><script>document.body.innerHTML = `headless: ${open("") !== null}`;</script>' ``